# Does the Higgs field explain inertia?

Tags: classical-mechanics, mass, higgs, inertia

As far as I understand it the Higgs field leads to the creation of rest mass for certain elementary particles but does it explain the phenomenon of resistance to acceleration associated with rest mass?

Comment: Related: [Intuitive explanation of how hadron mass emerges from the strong force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137127/intuitive-explanation-of-how-hadron-mass-emerges-from-the-strong-force/139874#139874)

Comment: See also https://profmattstrassler.com/2012/10/15/why-the-higgs-and-gravity-are-unrelated/.

Answer (score 1):

the most clarifying information about that that I am aware of is in a physics blog post (2007) by a physicist called Jim Pivarski, titlled [The origin of mass?](https://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2007/07/25/the-origin-of-mass/).

The theory of electroweak interaction offers a way of unifying the descriptions of electomagnetism and the weak nuclear interaction. This requires a mechanism to account for the fact that while the electromagnetic interaction is a long range interaction the weak nuclear interaction is inherently short range. This can be accounted for if the particle corresponding to the weak field is not massless, but instead has a significant inertial mass. Moreover, given the range of the weak nuclear interaction it could be predicted what that mass would have to be.

Pivarski writes that the Higgs mechanism is as far as known the only way to make the weak nuclear interaction short range.

In addition Pivarski points out the following: the quarks that together constitute a proton/neutron have a very high kinetic energy. The inertial mass of the proton/neutron is mainly the inertia corresponding to the confined kinetic energy of the quarks. This contribution to the inertial mass of the proton/neutron falls outside the scope of the Higgs mechanism.

In general the phenomenon that kinetic energy that is confined has a corresponding inertial mass is not accounted for by the Higgs mechanism.

Comment: Great blog post though I still don’t understand how “confined kinetic energy” leads to the resistance to acceleration which is the key characteristic of inertia.

Comment: @JohnEastmond About the qualification 'confined'. Compare the case of linear velocity. When a quantity of inertial mass is in linear motion there is no such thing as associating the corresponding kinetic energy with a specific volume of space; you can extend the linear motion forward and backward in time without limit. You can transform to a inertial coordinate system that is at rest with respect to the moving object; then the energy you attribute is only the rest mass. On the other hand, when you have a *bound system* the corresponding kinetic energy is *confined* to a finite volume of space.

Comment: @JohnEastmond Additional remark about 'finite volume of space': Let's say there is a fly-by of some interplanetary object, passing close to Earth. The amount of gravitational mass of that object is proportional to its rest mass, independent of the velocity of that object (up to relativistic velocity). Now a thought demonstration: an Ehrenfest disk. According to GR the kinetic energy of that spinning disk contributes to the gravitational mass of that disk.